# Let's Verify Step by Step: Old wine in new bottles?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, natural-language-processing, reference-request, training, rewards

In their paper ["Let's Verify Step by Step"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.20050) OpenAI proudly presents a new way of reward learning which shall foster LLMs' capabilities of mathematical and logical reasoning:

> We've trained a model to achieve a new state-of-the-art in
> mathematical problem solving by rewarding each correct step of
> reasoning (“process supervision”) instead of simply rewarding the
> correct final answer (“outcome supervision”).

But not to reward just the correct answer but each single correct step seems a general principle of modern didactics, so it sounds like old wine in new bottles, and it should not come as a surprise that it yields better results.

My question is: Is this really new state-of-the-art in machine learning and is there really no [prior art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_art)? In case there **is**, references are welcome.

To think one step further (not part of the question): Modern teachers might not only tell the student which steps were wrong and right, but also **explain** why. Shouldn't LLMs be able to understand such explanations (possibly in natural language) to improve their learning?